# Addresses in Modbus with C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, modbus, master-slave

I'm trying to communicate with [a microcontroller CL3-E from Nanotec](https://en.nanotec.com/fileadmin/files/Handbuecher/Motorsteuerungen/CL3-E/CL3E_CANopen_USB_ModbusRTU_Technical-Manual_V2.0.4.pdf) using the Modbus module with the RS232 connection. The program I've been able to develop lets me send messages to the microcontroller and receive messages from it.

Doing this and giving some tries to the program, I've seen that I constantly receive the same error with the same Exception Code (2). Searching in the Internet, I've seen it has something to do with the addresses and the mapping of them, but I'm not being able to see it. It is my first time programming a communication between devices, so, if apart of solving my question, you know some bibliography I could check, I would appreciate it!!!

The register number I'm trying to access is the 0x6060, and the function number is 0x10.

Comment: Exception code 2 indicates you are attempting to access an invalid address. Be sure to check the device manufacturer's Modbus datasheet. The Modbus specification does not enforce any particular mapping scheme, although there are several common mapping conventions. So, Read the Manufacturer's Datasheet, Check to make sure you are mapping registers properly, Check to see if there mapping scheme is 0 or 1 based. Also, if you update your question to include the register you are trying to read I could tell you the exact bytes to send.

Comment: @DanBarrett The manufacturer's datasheet is the one of the link! But I'm not being able to see how it is mapped. It is supposed to be in the part 9 of the manual, but i cannot see it pretty clear how it is done, maybe due to my lack of experience.

Comment: Again, please edit your post to include the register number and function code you are trying to access. I can't help you further until you do.

Comment: @DanBarrett done!

Comment: Page 269 says : "Not or incorrectly initialized pointer" which is a bad address.  If your commands a not aligned properly the message could be corrupt causing an address issue.  How many registers are you trying to write?

Comment: @jdweng but that, if I'm not wrong, refers to the execution of the NanoJ program. When I talk about the program, I'm refering to the PC program I've developed in C#, not the NanoJ program.

Comment: Why would the error message be different?

Comment: @jdweng because that error codes refer to the program which is in the controller, not the program which I've done. I cannot see the relationship between bth codes.

Comment: Are you using a C# modbus library or have you implemented your own protocol?

Comment: @DanBarrett I've implemented my own protocol, I guess. I haven't used the library, I write directly through the serial connection the bytes of information.

Comment: Alright, looking at the manual I believe you will need to map register 0x6060 to a PDO object. Function code 0x10 will attempt to write 1 or more 16 bit values. 0x6060 (ModesOfOperation) is an 8 bit value. 0x6061 is an 8 bit value that is readonly. I expect you are failing because it is trying to write to a readonly address.

Comment: @DanBarrett so, according to the manual, I can only map 16 register addresses, no?